# find records with an exact number of children

Tags: database, sqlite

Database structure:

Restaurant

- rID (Primary)

Retsau_Attribute

- id (primary)
- rID (foreign)
- aID (foreign)

Attributes

- aID (Primary)

I want to extract all the restaurant IDs that have all the attributes specified in the query.

I tried to use the IN operator, but it returns all restaurant IDs that have some or all of the attributes.

I used this query:

```
select rID from Retsau_Attribute where aID IN (a1, a2, a3);
```

I need only those restaurant IDs that have all the attributes specified (a1, a2, a3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grouping so that you can count the attributes per group:

```
SELECT rID
FROM Retsau_Attribute
WHERE aID IN (a1, a2, a3)
GROUP BY rID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge. CL